# How can we increase the fonsize of ag-grid data on context menu action?

Tags: angular6, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

I am using Angular 6 and ag grid version 18. I want to have an option from the context menu to increase and decrease the fontsize

I want a feature something like this. I tried rowstyle,cellstyle that did not work

Comment: See [ask], show us what you have done so far - the idea is to show what you have done, what are you expecting and what error you are getting. Also see how to create [mcve]

Comment: I want a feature something similar to this
https://plnkr.co/edit/h9eTLUfY1oGbFnmAt3gy?p=preview

Comment: add/update CSS class to the grid element once context menu item is clicked. You can set the font-size in CSS.

Comment: I am trying to return the same from the action function

Comment: this.fontSize += 1;
              const self=this;
              this.grid.gridOptions.getRowStyle = function() {
                return { 'font-size':self.fontSize+'px' }
              }
              this.grid.api.redrawRows();

It worked in this way.

Comment: With above option i am unable to increase font size of header need to do this as wel

Comment: again, read me last comment. try to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Below is how the column definition looks like. Note I am using variable `a` for incrementing and decrementing the font size -

```
var a = 10;
var columnDefs = [
    {headerName: 'Athlete', field: 'athlete', width: 150,
      cellStyle: function(params) {
        return {fontSize: params.context.a + 'px', backgroundColor: 'green'};
    }
    },
    ..
];
```

Set the reference to your component as below, this will be used in context menu callbacks -

```
var gridOptions = {
  context: this,
    ..
};
```

Below is the cell refresh and context menu -

```
function refreshCells() {
   var params = {
        force: true
    };
    gridOptions.api.refreshCells(params);
    
}
function getContextMenuItems(params) {
    var result = [
        {
            // custom item
            name: 'Increase Font',
            action: function() {
                params.context.a = params.context.a + 5;
                params.context.refreshCells();
            },
            
        },
        {
            // custom item
            name: 'Decrease Font',
            action: function() {
                params.context.a = params.context.a - 5;
                params.context.refreshCells();
            },
            
        }
    ];

    return result;
}
```

Please see Plunkr -
[Increase/decrease font ag-grid plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/GuXn5GjAE3kjWOC1gMdq?p=preview)

Comment: This is just increasing the size of rows. I want that to work for headers as well